# Docker Alpaline Cache issue, apk add curl not taking latest version

Tags: linux, docker, curl, dockerfile, alpine-package-keeper

After running first time, the docker cached curl script. now when I again run the pipepline docker cached and not taking latest version.

```
RUN apk update && apk add curl
```

--no-cache is not working
Any other solution, I want this command to execute run everytime and not cached.

Comment: Wrong apk tag removed (`apk` is for Android apk files, please read tag description befor using a tag)

Comment: I am curious.  I do not know much about Docker.  Well, other than my Docker pants.  Why did you choose to use Docker for your app?